# Colocar borda nas imagens inclusas no corpo das postagens

Tags: debate, layout, formatação, imagem

Vamos lá, é uma pergunta muito boa para tomar negativos mas vou perguntar assim mesmo.

É algo muito "bobo" mas acredito ser simples de implementar e resolver.

A questão é, é um pouco "trabalhoso" sempre ter que colocar bordas nas imagens antes de incluir no corpo de uma pergunta ou resposta.

O motivo é que o fundo das páginas é branco e muitas vezes eu faço ilustrações no mspaint onde o fundo é branco por padrão.

Quando posto fica estranho, misturando com o conteúdo em texto, então sempre faço uma borda qualquer para destacar a imagem do conteúdo em texto.

Isso é mais confuso quando fazemos um screenshot das próprias páginas do SO-pt.

Exemplo sem borda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Viu só como confunde bastante?

Inclusive eu mesmo já cliquei numa imagem pensando que fosse texto.

Existe uma linha pontilhada, mas é somente no bottom e na cor cinza.

Por isso de um tempo para cá venho tomando cuidado em sempre colocar uma borda. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aproveitando o embalo, as imagens poderiam abrir numa janela modal ou nova janela. Atualmente, quando clica, sobrepõe a página inteira. Diversas vezes eu fechei a imagem e perdi a página onde estava, fico com preguiça e nem volto mais. rsrs..

Comment: A linha pontilhada é justamente por causa do link, seu intuito não é servir de borda. Se tirar o link a borda pontilhada também some.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento meu comentário era direcionado para o Daniel, na parte que diz "Existe uma linha pontilhada, mas é somente no bottom e na cor cinza.", e para falar a verdade só agora entendi seu primeiro comentário, hehehe. Achei que você tava viajando.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento hehehe.. vamos esperar para ver o que o AP tem a dizer

Comment: É duplicata mesmo. Pode fechar

Comment: Putz.. agora que me lembrei dessa outra pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu também não gosto quando o fundo branco se mistura com o branco da imagem, e eu mesmo costumo colocar borda nas minhas imagens, só que de uma maneira mais fácil que abrir em um editor de texto.

Costumo fazer às vezes usando `<kbd></kbd>`:

<kbd>[image: imagem aqui]</kbd>

E às vezes usando simplesmente o `>`

> [image: imagem aqui]

Vale lembrar que no site principal o `>` fica amarelo enquanto no meta fica cinza, igual no exemplo acima.

Eu concordo que poderia ter uma forma mais simples de fazer isso pois principalmente quem é iniciante no site provavelmente vai acabar postando muitas coisas sem o contorno deixando muitas postagens no site assim.

Poderia por exemplo ser algo tomado como padrão no sitema assim como a imagem que recentemente mudou para virem com um link para abrí-la ocupando a tela inteira, mas que se o usuário que está postando deseja tirá-lo é perfeitamente possível. Uma solicitação de novo recurso talvez seja uma boa para esse assunto.

Sobre a imagem que se abre na mesma aba no lugar do conteúdo da página você pode contornar esse problema abrindo ela em uma nova aba, não é complicado, não vejo motivos para discutir isso.

Comment: Boa ideia. Nunca pensei em usar as tags do editor para fazer isso e desconhecia essa tag "kbd". Interessante saber também que a tag de citação funciona para isso.

Comment: Sobre a imagem abrir na mesma janela, como já me acostumei, eu abro numa nova aba. Acho que todo mouse moderno tem aquela rodinha no centro https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPdLx.jpg. Quando aperta a rodinha, abre o link em nova aba. Mas as vezes esqueço e clico normalmente.

Comment: Poisé, ainda é possível abrir em uma nova aba segurando o Ctrl enquanto clica